# Calculating collision for a moving circle, without overlapping the boundaries

Tags: physics

Let's say I have circle bouncing around inside a rectangular area. At some point this circle will collide with one of the surfaces of the rectangle and reflect back. The usual way I'd do this would be to let the circle overlap that boundary and then reflect the velocity vector. The fact that the circle actually overlaps the boundary isn't usually a problem, nor really noticeable at low velocity. At high velocity it becomes quite clear that the circle is doing something it shouldn't.

What I'd like to do is to programmatically take reflection into account and place the circle at it's proper position before displaying it on the screen. This means that I have to calculate the point where it hits the boundary between it's current position and it's future position -- rather than calculating it's new position and then checking if it has hit the boundary.

This is a little bit more complicated than the usual circle/rectangle collision problem. I have a vague idea of how I should do it -- basically create a bounding rectangle between the current position and the new position, which brings up a slew of problems of it's own (Since the rectangle is rotated according to the direction of the circle's velocity). However, I'm thinking that this is a common problem, and that a common solution already exists.

Is there a common solution to this kind of problem? Perhaps some basic theories which I should look into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you just have a circle and a rectangle, it's actually pretty simple. A circle of radius `r` bouncing around inside a rectangle of dimensions `w, h` can be treated the same as a point `p` at the circle's center, inside a rectangle `(w-r), (h-r)`.

Now position update becomes simple. Given your point at position `x, y` and a per-frame velocity of `dx, dy`, the updated position is `x+dx, y+dy` - except when you cross a boundary. If, say, you end up with `x+dx > W` (letting `W = w-r`), then you do the following:

```
crossover = (x+dx) - W // this is how far "past" the edge your ball went
x = W - crossover // so you bring it back the same amount on the correct side
dx = -dx // and flip the velocity to the opposite direction
```

And similarly for `y`. You'll have to set up a similar (reflected) check for the opposite boundaries in each dimension.

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

At each step, you can calculate the projected/expected position of the circle for the next frame.

If this lies outside the rectangle, then you can then use the distance from the old circle position to the rectangle's edge and the amount "past" the rectangle's edge that the next position lies at (the interpenetration) to linearly interpolate and determine the precise time when the circle "hits" the rectangle edge.

For example, if the circle is 10 pixels away from the rectangle's edge, then is predicted to move to 5 pixels beyond it, you know that for 2/3rds of the timestep (10/15ths) it moves on its orginal path, then is reflected and continues on its new path for the remaining 1/3rd of the timestep (5/15ths). By calculating these two parts of the motion and "adding" the translations together, you can find the correct new position.

(Of course, it gets more complicated if you hit near a corner, as there may be several collisions during the timestep, off different edges. And if you have more than one circle moving, things get a lot more complex. But that's where you can start for the case you've asked about)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection across a rectangular boundary is incredibly simple.  Just take the amount that the object passed the boundary and subtract it from the boundary position.  If the position without reflecting would be (-0.8,-0.2) for example and the upper left corner is at (0,0), the reflected position would be (0.8,0.2).