# Circle-Rectangle's border collision detection

Tags: math, geometry, collision-detection

How can I tell whether a **circle tangents the outer rectangle or is located (partially) outside of the rectangle** in 2D Euclidean space?

The rectangle will always be aligned with the axes.
[image: Visual representation of a circle-rectangle's border collision]

Basically I'm creating a simple game with a ball which moves in certain steps with a certain angle through the space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating collision for a moving circle, without overlapping the boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751377/calculating-collision-for-a-moving-circle-without-overlapping-the-boundaries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote the four sides of the rectangle `s1, s2, s3, s4` starting from the top and moving clockwise.

Check the distance from the circle's centre to each of the four lines; `d1, d2, d3, d4` (numbered corresponding to the sides). Note that there is a simple formula to derive the (orthogonal) distance from a point to a line.

A necessary (although not sufficient) condition is that the distance from one of the lines is the radius length (pragmatically the difference is less than some delta of your choosing):
`|d1 - r| < delta || ...`

You can make this a sufficient condition if the circle is totally inside the rectangle, which is true iff each distance is less than the distance between the corresponding sides of the rectangle, less the radius:
`d1 <= |s1 - s3|-r && d2 <= |s2 - s4|-r && ...`

Checking partially outside is as simple as checking for the opposite of the last paragraph (and if you require, checking that the radius is still within the box):
`d1 > |s1 - s3|-r || d2 > |s2 - s4|-r || ...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm sorry I forgot to say that my circle moves in certain steps, so there is a chance (depending on user's screen resolution, ...) that the circle never tangents the rectangle.

Comment: @ComFreek, you take the mathematical model and interpolate your motion in two ways: (1) create a delta value that is large enough but not too large (2) split your motion: take two points, and even though they are two adjacent frames of animation, calculate some number of intermediate frames, say 50, and on each one perform the calculations.