# Solve intersection between ball and rectangle

Tags: language-agnostic, physics

I have a ball and a rectangle. The ball can move, the rectangle is fixed(mass = infinite).

The ball has a position, a velocity, a radius, a mass.

The rectangle has a position, a width and a height.

I have already functions that detect collision when they collide and calculate correct response, but I have problem to resolve the intersection before calculate correct response.
In an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq5Vk.png

I use Java.

**EDIT: Solved by using this algorithm:**

1. Calculate the closest point (I call it P) between the rectangle bounds and ball
   (easy to do with Clamp function)
2. Calculate vector (I call it n) that link the ball center point (I call it C) and P
   (the vector's components are (P.x - C.x, P.y - C.y))
3. Calculate the "lenght" of the intersection (I call it offset)
   (ball.radius - n.length)
4. Normalize n and multiply by offset.
5. Subtract n to ball position vector.

in Java code:

```
    private void resolveIntersectionWith(Ball ball){
        double closestX = clamp(ball.position.x, left(), right());
        double closestY = clamp(ball.position.y, top(), bottom());

        Vector n = new Vector(closestX - ball.position.x, closestY - ball.position.y);
        double offset = ball.radius - n.length;
        n.normalize().multiply(offset);
        ball.position.subtract(n);
    }
```

Comment: Is this similar? [Calculating collision for a moving circle, without overlapping the boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2751377/427192)

Comment: Yes is similar but the solution won't work for me.. I'll do other tests

Comment: I think the solution does not work because the ball in your link is inside the rectangle. In my problem the ball is outside!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these intersections you should move the ball towards away from the rektangle until it is not hit anymore.

A simple way to do this is to calculate the point Q in the rektangle closest to the ball centre P. Then move the ball away from this point as

```
P=P+(P-Q)*(r/abs(P-Q)-1)
```

where r is the radius.
Alternative you can step with smaller timesteps to avoid intersection

EDIT: Missclick

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by how you detect collision. I am assuming that your checking whether the ball is on or within the boundaries of the rectangle or not. In this situation you already have updated the position to be within the rectangle. However if you would check if a collision would occur after you add the velocity to its position (`x += v * dt`), you would be able to determine the exact time of collision, which would mean that the ball would move the remaining time of this iteration in the new direction.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I solved my problem in an other way.